# Pressing enter doesn't send input

Tags: python, input

Hi I am a beginner to Python. I am writing the following sample code for input but when I press `Enter` after entering value for input command, the program doesn't go forward after printing the first line. I've done it in both Atom and Sublime Text. A basic print statement works perfect.

```
print ("hello")
x = input("Enter value")
print(x)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? [Edit] your question to include the output of your program, and the python interpreter version you're using

Answer (score 1):

Sublime does not support user input unless you install a third-party plugin. And Atom is no different.

If you like to input values interactively, I would suggest running your script from the app Python IDLE then go to file and open your Python script and run it.

Or, alternatively, open a CMD (if you are PC user) or Terminal (in case of MacOS) and execute your script directly from the command line interface, like below:

> python yourscript.py

Answer (score 0):

may be the problem is with the code editor. Try running the file using cmd if you are on windows or terminal on mac/linux.

```
python file_name.py
```

Comment: So, using the cmd for taking inputs will be a better idea